# TYPO3 Real URL not working

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, realurl

I was trying wo get the real url extension on my own extension to run but it is not working.

Where is my mistake?

How ist is possible that my own extension has some nice URL's?

My URL
    http://domain.tld/eigenprojekte/project/show/test

My realutl_conf.php

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
  '_DEFAULT' => 
  array (
    'init' => 
    array (
      'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
      'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'pagePath' => 
    array (
      'rootpage_id' => '1',
    ),
    'fileName' => 
    array (
      'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
      'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
      'index' => 
      array (
        'print' => 
        array (
          'keyValues' => 
          array (
            'type' => 98,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
    'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(
            'eigenprojekte' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_eigenprojekte_eigenprojekte[controller]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_eigenprojekte_eigenprojekte[show]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_eigenprojekte_eigenprojekte[project]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_eigenprojekte_domain_model_project',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'project',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you generate link with fluid `f:link.action` ?

Comment: The url i posted is not working 
I get following error message:
Reason: Segment "project" was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page with id=5.

Answer (score 1):

First Check configuration for realURl. Please add this two line if you have not added in setup.ts file.

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

In your realutl_conf.php file change the below line.

```
'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(
            .....
            ........
            array(
               'GETvar' => 'tx_eigenprojekte_eigenprojekte[action]', // add action keyword Not action name
            ),

           .........
           ..........
```

Also you can use `fixedPostVars` like below.

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
      '19'=> array(
          array(
              'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
              'noMatch' => 'bypass',
          ),
          array(
              'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
              'noMatch' => 'bypass',
          ),
     ),
),
```

Here `19` is your page id